# Move Lolliplot R

Tags: r

I'm trying to move the Lolliplot so that all of the labels are on the plot.
I am following the vignette here [Lolliplot vignette](https://bioc.ism.ac.jp/packages/3.7/bioc/vignettes/trackViewer/inst/doc/trackViewer.html#adjust-x-axis-or-x-scale) and using the trackViewer library with GRanges but I can't find how to either:

1. move the plot down or
2. make the labels smaller

Please help!

[image: Lolliplot]

Comment: Looking at the [source code for the plotLollipops.R function](https://github.com/jianhong/trackViewer/blob/master/R/plotLollipops.R) there is a lot going on. Have you tried adjusting the margins prior to plotting? E.g. run `par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 8.1, 2.1))` before running the rest of the code?

Comment: @jared_mamrot, thanks but this didn't change the plot :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify the size of the png you can ensure the plot 'fits', e.g. (from the vignette):

```r
library(Gviz)
library(rtracklayer)
library(trackViewer)

extdata <- system.file("extdata", package="trackViewer",
                       mustWork=TRUE)
SNP <- c(10, 12, 1400, 1402)
sample.gr <- GRanges("chr1", IRanges(SNP, width=1, names=paste0("snp", SNP)))
features <- GRanges("chr1", IRanges(c(1, 501, 1001), 
                                    width=c(120, 400, 405),
                                    names=paste0("block", 1:3)))

SNP2 <- sample(4000:8000, 30)
x2 <- sample.int(100, length(SNP2), replace=TRUE)
sample2.gr <- GRanges("chr3", IRanges(SNP2, width=1, names=paste0("snp", SNP2)), 
                      value1=x2, value2=100-x2)
sample2.gr$color <- rep(list(c('#DB7575', '#FFD700')), length(SNP2))
sample2.gr$border <- "gray30"

features2 <- GRanges("chr3", IRanges(c(5001, 5801, 7001), 
                                     width=c(500, 500, 405),
                                     names=paste0("block", 4:6)),
                     fill=c("orange", "gray30", "lightblue"),
                     height=unit(c(0.5, 0.3, 0.8), "cm"))
legends <- list(list(labels=c("WT", "MUT"), fill=c("#87CEFA", '#98CE31')), 
                list(labels=c("WT", "MUT"), fill=c('#DB7575', '#FFD700')))
rand.id <- sample.int(length(sample.gr), 3*length(sample.gr), replace=TRUE)
rand.id <- sort(rand.id)
sample.gr.mul.patient <- sample.gr[rand.id]
## pie.stack require metadata "stack.factor", and the metadata can not be 
## stack.factor.order or stack.factor.first
len.max <- max(table(rand.id))
stack.factors <- paste0("patient", formatC(1:len.max, 
                                           width=nchar(as.character(len.max)), 
                                           flag="0"))
sample.gr.mul.patient$stack.factor <- 
  unlist(lapply(table(rand.id), sample, x=stack.factors))
sample.gr.mul.patient$value1 <- 
  sample.int(100, length(sample.gr.mul.patient), replace=TRUE)
sample.gr.mul.patient$value2 <- 100 - sample.gr.mul.patient$value1
patient.color.set <- as.list(as.data.frame(rbind(rainbow(length(stack.factors)), 
                                                 "#FFFFFFFF"), 
                                           stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
names(patient.color.set) <- stack.factors
sample.gr.mul.patient$color <- 
  patient.color.set[sample.gr.mul.patient$stack.factor]
legend <- list(labels=stack.factors, col="gray80", 
               fill=sapply(patient.color.set, `[`, 1))
features.mul <- rep(features, 2)
features.mul$height[4:6] <- list(unit(1/8, "inches"),
                                 unit(0.5, "lines"),
                                 unit(.2, "char"))
features.mul$fill <- c("#FF8833", "#F9712A", "#DFA32D", 
                       "#51C6E6", "#009DDA", "#4B9CDF")
end(features.mul)[5] <- end(features.mul[5])+50
features.mul$featureLayerID <- 
  paste("tx", rep(1:2, each=length(features)), sep="_")
names(features.mul) <- 
  paste(features.mul$featureLayerID, 
        rep(1:length(features), 2), sep="_")
sample2.gr$score <- sample2.gr$value1
sample2.gr$SNPsideID <- "top"
idx <- sample.int(length(sample2.gr), 15)
sample2.gr$SNPsideID[idx] <- "bottom"
sample2.gr$color[idx] <- '#FFD700'
lolliplot(list(A=sample.gr, B=sample2.gr), 
          list(x=features.mul, y=features2), 
          type=c("pie", "circle"), legend=legends)
```

[image]

This plot (above) is 'chopped off', but if you save the plot as a png, you can specify the size of the 'canvas' to ensure the plot 'fits' properly:

```r
png("example.png", width = 960, height = 900)
lolliplot(list(A=sample.gr, B=sample2.gr), 
          list(x=features.mul, y=features2), 
          type=c("pie", "circle"), legend=legends)
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

[image: example.png]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>